# How to get an Android phone's IMEI number from TestComplete?

Tags: android, automated-tests, testcomplete

I'm writing automated tests using TestComplete. Is there a way to get an Android phone's IMEI number from TestComplete scripts?

To clarify: I'm NOT writing an Android app, so I don't have access to Android APIs.

Answer (score 0):

To read IMEI you need to have following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

and then call:

[`android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId())